# Android: Placing the Buttons below the Text and not in the same line

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am making a simple Android Application.

This is the XML code:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Score: "
    tools:context=".Adder" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="0"
    tools:context=".Adder" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/two"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="2"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

which is giving the output: http://flic.kr/p/dqwmT9

But, I want the Buttons to be present below the "Score: 0"

I have tried a few things, which are giving the output: http://flic.kr/p/dqwbxD

What can I do to fix this?

NOTE: I have given the link because I do not have enough reputation to upload photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Relative Layout instead of Linear Layout.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/one"
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/score_text"
android:text="1"
android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. You can, in fact, just copy and paste it. Change the attributes and you are good to go.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScoreLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Score" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txtScoreLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtScoreLabel"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtScoreLabel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtScoreLabel"
        android:text="Button One" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/two"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/one"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/one"
        android:text="Button Two" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a `RelativeLayout` Then assign an id to the TextView that shows "Score":

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/score_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="Score: "
    tools:context=".Adder" />
```

Then you have assign position to the Buttons based on that:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/score_text"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/score_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/one"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

to the parent layout (if it is a `LinearLayout`).
If your parent Layout is a `RealativeLayout`you have to set

```
android:below="id of the view above"
```

to the buttons you want to have below the `TextView`.

Edit(Since your ParentLayout is a `LinearLayout`):

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Score: "
        tools:context=".Adder" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/score"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0"
        tools:context=".Adder" />
    <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/two"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
    />

/>
```

Comment: wrap the buttons in a LinearLayout and set the orientation to horizontal